# How to show an image gives the unit square?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be the parallelogram distended
by two vectors $\begin{pmatrix}a \\ b\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}c \\ d\end{pmatrix}$ which are not parallel, and let $M = \begin{pmatrix}a & c \\ b & d\end{pmatrix}$.

Show that the image $$\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \:= \:\textbf{T} \begin{pmatrix}u \\ v \end{pmatrix} \:=\: M\begin{pmatrix}u \\ v\end{pmatrix}$$

images the unit square $K$ distended by $\textbf{e}_1$ and $\textbf{e}_2$ on $A.$

The only work i can show is:

$M\begin{pmatrix}u \\ v\end{pmatrix} \:=\:\begin{pmatrix}a & c \\ b & d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u \\ v\end{pmatrix} \: = \:\begin{pmatrix}au \: +\:cv\\bu \: + \: dv \end{pmatrix}$.

I would like to know exactly what they are asking, so a clarification would be nice in adition to some hints on how this is supposed to be done. My apologize in advance if i'm not making myself clear, i have a very limiting vocabulary in linalg:)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$M\textbf{e}_1=M\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \:=\:\begin{pmatrix}a & c \\ b & d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \: = \:\begin{pmatrix}a \\b  \end{pmatrix}$$
and:
$$M\textbf{e}_2=M\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \:=\:\begin{pmatrix}a & c \\ b & d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \: = \:\begin{pmatrix}c\\d \end{pmatrix}$$
Thus:
$$M(
\lambda\textbf{e}_1+\mu\textbf{e}_2)=\lambda\begin{pmatrix}a \\b  \end{pmatrix}+\mu\begin{pmatrix}c\\d \end{pmatrix}$$
Do you see now how it goes from here?

Comment: I really am trying to understand what is going on here, and your first two equations are easy to follow, however on the last one you show that we get a scaling factor of the parallelogram with eigenvalues $\lambda, \mu$ if i'm not mistaking? I still don't understand how this relates to the unit square? Thanks for reply

Comment: I just mean that any linear combination of $\textbf{e}_1$ and $\textbf{e}_2$ "maps" (under $M$) to the same linear combination of $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$. Consequently, the primary diagonal of the unit square "maps" to the primary diagonal of the parallelogram defined by $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$, the secondary diagonal of the unit square "maps" to the secondary diagonal of the parallelogram defined by $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$, and any point inside the unit square maps into a point inside the parallelogram defined by $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$

Comment: Thanks alot, that made it all much clearer!